# .NET version compatibility issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have developed an MVC 3 (using .NET 4.0 and not .NET 3.5 SP1) application with jQuery Mobile that communicates with a legacy application's business layer built in 3.5. Now the time has come to upload the application to a production server. However issues have arised. Namely, the client insists that the mvc app should be a sub app of a desktop version of the same app (built in 3.5). What do I do now?

Comment: What do you mean by "the web app should be a sub app of the desktop app"?

Comment: desktop version of the same app. Means meant to run on PCs

Comment: So, you have a written a web app and now the customer wants it to run as a desktop app?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying... sounds like you didn't have things documented up-front here as far as what the requirements were.

Answer (score 2):

You could use IIS Express to host the web application locally. IIS Express can be packaged within an application installer and distributed to the users.

The desktop app can then have a simplified browser window that navigates to the local web application.

... an ugly solution to a problem that shouldn't exist.